# List of tanks that come with free BIA skill crew?

Tags: world-of-tanks

What tanks have been sold/given with crew having free (not resetable, 0-skill) "Brothers in Arms" skill?

I bought many of them and I would like to track them. I know how to check crew for free skill, I just do not want to check all my tanks. I retrained some crews so maybe I have tank that comes with such crew but currently has other/no crew.

Edit: I am mostly interested in EU server, but I am sure for most of tanks its same and minor differences can be pointed out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are all the ones I could find. To be clear, some of these tanks may have been available without zero-skill crews. This is the list of tanks that have had the possibility of purchasing or earning them with such crews.

- Russia: IS-2, IS-2M, ISU-122S, KV-2 (R), SU-130PM, T-34-85 Rudy
- UK: Cromwell B, Caernarvon Action X
- USA: M4A3E8 Thunderbolt VII
- Germany: Tiger 131
- Poland: Pudel
- Sweden: Primo Victoria
- Japan (SEA server only): Edelweiss,    Nameless

Additionally, the Loza's M4-A2 Sherman commmander has zero-skill sixth sense. So does the special mission reward crew member Gianluigi "Gigi" Buffon.

[Source](http://do_all_countries_have_zeroskill_bia_premiums_and) for some of the above. I was able to find the rest of these by searching

```
site:https://worldoftanks.com/en/news/: "zero-skill"
```

I checked the [Strv. m/42 57](https://worldoftanks.eu/en/news/premium-shop/premshop-strv-first-swedish/) because someone on the forum mentioned it, but it was available with "Crew: 100% Major Qualifications + trained Brothers in Arms perk". Sounds like BiA was first skill, not zero-skill.

Comment: Sadly on EU server Pudel has standard 50% crew.

Comment: @Piro that's unfortunate. On NA the "Pudel Loaded" and "Pudel Ultimate" packages came with the zero-skill crew, but it was possible to purchase the tank by itself without a crew for less money. https://worldoftanks.com/en/news/premium-shop/the-pudel-polish-tank/

Comment: @Piro it is a little less clear on EU. The more expensive Pudel packages say they come with "100% trained crew for the Pudel with the 'Brothers in Arms' perk", but they probably mean zero-skill BiA. https://worldoftanks.eu/en/news/premium-shop/pudel-introduction/

Comment: I [asked on forum and players confirm](http://forum.worldoftanks.eu/index.php?/topic/692345-pudel-with-0-skill-bia/) pudel had 0-skill BIA

Comment: Wow, 6 Soviet tanks and 5 of all other nations together (excluding Japan)...

Answer (score -1):

Caernarvon Action X
See: https://worldoftanks.com/en/news/announcements/caernarvon-action-x-last-chance-0918/
Fully trained "zero-Skill" Crew withBrothers in Arms Perk

Comment: While the links are helpful, it would be better to copy the relevant portions here in a formatted code block. [Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)